# WebSocket with angular 6 gets destroyed

Tags: python, angular, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to learn how to use WebSocket with a python backend and an Angular 6 front end.
It looks like the WebSocket connection gets destroy as the updates does only work when I put a breakpoint on the following line:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.socketService.getQuotes()
  .subscribe(quote => {
    console.log('got price: ' + quote);
    this.price = quote;
  });
} // breakpoint
```

The backend is pretty simple:

```
def send_market_price():
    threading.Timer(5.0, send_market_price).start()
    print('sending price ws')
    socketio.emit('market', market.update_market())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_market_price()
    print('starting')
    socketio.run(app)
```

the service is basic too:

```
@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  public socket;
  public observer: Observer<number>;

  getQuotes(): Observable<number> {
    this.socket = socketio(SERVER_URL);

    this.socket.on('market', (res) => {
      this.observer.next(res);
    });

    return this.createObservable();
  }

 createObservable(): Observable<number> {
   return new Observable(observer => {
   this.observer = observer;
 });
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code to do this basic feature?

EDIT

after some tests, it looks like that the backend is bugged. I did the same thing getting a Node.js code and it works great.

What is wrong with this python code:

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

from market_engine import market
from market_engine.market import RandomMarket

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
CORS(app)
market = RandomMarket()

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

def send_market_price():
    threading.Timer(5.0, send_market_price).start()
    print('sending price ws')
    socketio.emit('market', market.update_market())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_market_price()
    print('starting')
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by: "It looks like the websocket connection gets destroy as the updates does only work when I put a break point on the following line:"? 

What does adding a break point change?

Comment: when I add a breakpoint I can see "got price: ...." after I resume the program, and this.price is changed a couple of time. After releasing the breakpoint, no more changes. Without adding a breakpoint, I never see "got price: ..."

Comment: Do you have eventlet or gevent installed in your virtual environment? If you do, then you can't use the threading functions of the Python standard library, which are not async compatible. You can monkey-patch the standard library to replace those functions with async friendly versions.